# How can I query a random date from this api?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using the NASA api to fetch images of Mars.  I am using retrofit to fetch the data.  The Mars API states a query can be done by "sol"...or in other words, day rotation on mars.  I am able to get the data when I call it by the specific sol, but I want the user to be shown a random date every time they enter the app. What is the correct way to implement this?

[Example JSON](https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&api_key=DEMO_KEY)

MarsPhotoApi.kt

```
interface MarsPhotoApi {

    @GET("/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos")

    suspend fun getCuriosityData(
        @Query("sol")
        solQuery: Int,
        @Query("rover_id")
        roverQuery: Int,
        @Query("camera")
        camera: String,
        @Query("api_Key")
        apiKey: String = API_KEY
    ): Response<MarsPhotos>

}
```

MarsPhotoViewModel.kt

```
class MarsPhotoViewModel(
    val marsPhotoRepository: MarsPhotoRepository
    ): ViewModel() {

    val marsPhotos: MutableLiveData<Resource<MarsPhotos>> = MutableLiveData()

    init {

        getCuriosityPhotos(1, 5, "NAVCAM")
    }

    fun getCuriosityPhotos(solQuery: Int, roverQuery: Int, camera: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        marsPhotos.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        val response = marsPhotoRepository.getCuriosityPhotos(solQuery, roverQuery, camera)
        marsPhotos.postValue(handlePhotosResponse(response))
    }



    private fun handlePhotosResponse(response: Response<MarsPhotos> ) : Resource<MarsPhotos> {
        if(response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()?.let { resultResponse ->
                return Resource.Success(resultResponse)
            }
        }
        return Resource.Error(response.message())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could just use a random Int for the sol value
`Random.nextInt(1, 2000)`

Comment: where would you add this?  I am thinking it would be called on the query of MarsPhotoApi

Comment: Wherever makes sense for your setup.